# regex capturing multiple string placeholders

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that would capture all occurences of `{alphabetical}` inside a string (let it be none, one or more), for instance:

- `This is a {variable}` -> `[variable]`
- `This is a {variable} and this is {another} one` -> `[variable, another]`
- `This is a {variable} and this is {another} {one}`  -> `[variable, another, one]`

I've managed to do `/(\{[a-z]+})/` (tested here: https://regex101.com/), but it just captures the first occurence. Please help me with capturing all occurences and catching them into the groups.

Comment: use `g` flag: https://regex101.com/r/cE3aQ1/1

Comment: that solved it! :)

Answer (score 1):

To capture more occurences, use `g` flag: [regex101.com/r/cE3aQ1/1](http://regex101.com/r/cE3aQ1/1)